# How to generate a unique request ID in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I need a unique request ID for my logger, so I can track each request in the log file.

So far I got this

```
REQUEST_ID = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Time.now.to_f.to_s + $PID.to_s)
```

The problem is that I don't know where to put this. I tried placing it inside my custom logger file, outside the class. But it must be being cached or something because I'm always getting the same hash.

Any ideas?

note. I'm using Rails 3 and Passenger standalone

**UPDATE:**

Rails 3.2 :uuid tag won't work. Look how badly formatted the logs are:

```
[0909413851b79676cb06e0842d21c466] [127.0.0.1] 

Started HEAD "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Feb 21 14:08:25 -0300 2012
[0909413851b79676cb06e0842d21c466] [127.0.0.1] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
[0909413851b79676cb06e0842d21c466] [127.0.0.1] bla
[0909413851b79676cb06e0842d21c466] [127.0.0.1]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
```

In production this will be a mess. Notice the newlines after the first line? Now imagine how the logs would look like in a server handling many requests per second. It will be hard to associate a request with a URI

Comment: HappyDeveloper, @SergioTulentsev nailed it! I'm deleting my answer; please accept his.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to insert the request UUID at the log line `Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Feb 21 14:00:00 -0300 2012`, you can patch or subclass `Rails::Rack::Logger` to modify the `call_app` method:

```
def call_app(env)
  request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
  path = request.filtered_path
  Rails.logger.info "\n\nStarted #{request.request_method} \"#{path}\" for #{request.ip} at #{Time.now.to_default_s}"
  @app.call(env)
ensure
  ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.flush_all!
end
```

The request object is created right before the logging statement, so you can change the logging statement to include `request.uuid`.

Comment: As of rails 3.2 - you can also override the `started_request_message` method - https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/35a17502b6054ab6d6407c0af902a441e8ae8215

Answer (score 39):

Rails core team took care of it for you!

Rails 3.2 introduces `request.uuid` method, which returns, um, unique request identifier, which looks like this: `ab939dfca5d57843ea4c695cab6f721d`.

See [release notes here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#action-dispatch).

Also take a look [at this awesome screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2?view=asciicast) to know how to use this new method with logging.

```
# config/environments/development.rb 
config.log_tags = [:uuid, :remote_ip]


# log file
[ab939dfca5d57843ea4c695cab6f721d] [127.0.0.1] 

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-27 21:52:58 +0000
[ab939dfca5d57843ea4c695cab6f721d] [127.0.0.1] Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
[ab939dfca5d57843ea4c695cab6f721d] [127.0.0.1]   Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT &quot;products&quot;.* FROM &quot;products&quot; 
[ab939dfca5d57843ea4c695cab6f721d] [127.0.0.1]   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (22.0ms)
[ab939dfca5d57843ea4c695cab6f721d] [127.0.0.1] Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 73.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
[98eec5f8976586c1165b981797086b6a] [127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Is there more documentation about this? What other tags can I add? Also, it's adding ugly spaces as in the logs you posted (see the spaces before 'Rendered'). Do you know if I can access the uuid from the outside to make my own logger?

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: yep, it's a method on a `request` object. So you can access it in your controllers, `logger.debug request.uuid`.

Comment: But I need to access the request id from within my initializer because logs start before the controller. Right? What can I do? I'm still stuck with this

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: if you have a custom logger, you can just pass `request.uuid` as another parameter to logging call. You don't need to do this in initializer, because, naturally, you don't have request at that point.

Comment: If I can't put the request ID in the very first line of the request logs, then it's useless. I need it to be written in this line: rails[13273][$REQUEST_ID]: Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Feb 21 14:00:00 -0300 2012. So far everything works except for the request id part. I need to grab it or generate it somehow.

Comment: Ok, happy researching then :)

Answer (score 6):

Follow-up to the answer using `log_tags`, since :uuid is only unique among a request, it is difficult to use it with session tracking.

I found log_tags accept a Proc, and pass a request object as an parameter. So, following code will stamp all of log entry with session_id (assuming you're using ActiveRecord based session store)

```
config.log_tags = [ lambda {|req| "#{req.cookie_jar["_session_id"]}" }, :remote_ip, :uuid  ]
```