# How to monkey patch RequestId middleware or why does Heroku not use the standard HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID?

Tags: ruby, logging, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Heroku rolled out a [new labs feature for tracking http-request-id](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id) from its router.

A little background why that's useful: Rails 3.2's rolled out a feature with its TaggedLogger to [include a unique request ID into the logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9380164/459863), so that you can track which web request a given log line belongs to. This is really important when running multiple web servers that stream their logs to the same logging store, e.g. as is common with multiple dynos on Heroku or Unicorn setups, etc.

Now, with Heroku's labs feature, the Heroku router will generate this request ID, so that you can track the request from the router level before it even enters the application. This is important, e.g. if the request failed to complete, due to timeout, etc.

Unfortunately Heroku didn't choose the standard request header key for this, `HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID` which Rails would accept and pass through, but instead made up a custom one, `HTTP_HEROKU_REQUEST_ID`, which Rails will not pass through without modifications. ***Heroku, why this deviation from convention here?***

So, I'm left with two choices: Either replace the Rails default `RequestId` middleware with a copy & paste job that uses Heroku's header key, or to monkey patch the Rails middleware. I don't like copy & paste jobs because they're not DRY and easily go stale, leaving the monkey patch as the better option. How to go about this, though?

I tried adding a file `config/initializers/middleware.rb` with:

```
module ActionDispatch
  class RequestId
    private
    def external_request_id(env)
      if request_id = env["HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID"].presence || env['HTTP_HEROKU_REQUEST_ID'].presence
        request_id.gsub(/[^\w\-]/, "").first(255)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But that doesn't get executed. How can I patch this?

Comment: There's a gem out there now doing this for you: [HerokuRequestId](https://github.com/Octo-Labs/heroku-request-id).

Answer (score 4):

There's a solution to that!
I just added this to my production.rb and it works!

```
  config.log_tags = [lambda {|req| req.env['HTTP_HEROKU_REQUEST_ID']}]
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712252/2422778 and Railscasts

**EDIT**
Just wanted to point out that as of 17 Jan 2014 Heroku fixed request id header name and it's now

```
env['HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID']
```

see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id

Comment: That works for the logs. I'd like to pass the request ID to background jobs also for tracking. Not being able to use Rails's request.uuid is a major drawback.

Comment: So why can't you take it from requexrt.env and pass further?